# Perform operations in different IE tabs

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to search for city in one IE tab then open my generated link in another tab. If I run these operations separately everything work however I am not able to make it work all together. What is possibly wrong?

Debugger points to `.Document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Dublin"` saying

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': Method 'Document' of object
>   'IWebBrowser 2' failed

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub GetFlightRates()
Dim appIE As Object
Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

With appIE
    .Navigate "https://maps.google.com"
    .Document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Dublin"
    .Document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox-searchbutton")(0).Click

    .Navigate "https://www.google.co.in/flights/", CLng(2048) '2nd
    .Visible = True
End With

Do While appIE.Busy
    DoEvents
Loop

'appIE.Quit
Set appIE = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Is your link generated definitely valid when this fails? Can you share what the second link you navigate to looks like in full (not concatenation formula) when fails?

Comment: @QHarr question edited. It doesn't work even like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a page load wait before attempting to access .document

```
Option Explicit
Sub OpenTabs()
    Dim appIE As Object
    Set appIE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

    With appIE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://maps.google.com"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        .document.getElementsByName("q")(0).Value = "Dublin"
        .document.getElementsByClassName("searchbox-searchbutton")(0).Click

        .navigate "https://www.google.co.in/flights/", CLng(2048) '2nd
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
    End With

    Stop
    'appIE.Quit
    Set appIE = Nothing
End Sub
```